# In app purchase test credential

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can we use test account credentail after submitting app to appstore to make purchases. What is the validation time period of the test account credential?

Answer (score 1):

No, test accounts do not work on apps which are live on the AppStore. Test accounts only work in the sandbox environment. This is stated in [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html):

> When you launch your application from Xcode, Store Kit does not
>   connect to the App Store. Instead, it connects to a special sandbox
>   store environment. The sandbox environment uses the infrastructure of
>   the App Store, but it does not process actual payments. It returns
>   transactions as if payments were processed successfully. The sandbox
>   environment uses special iTunes Connect accounts that are limited to
>   In-App Purchase testing.

Once you publish the app on AppStore, the app starts pointing to the live AppStore (it does not go to the sandbox environment).